# assign multiple categorical values to series of data frame variables in r

Tags: r, variable-assignment, multiple-variable-return

Say I have the following data input into R

```
G <- c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) 
H <- c(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0) 
I <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0) 
J <- c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0) 
K <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0) 
L <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)

list <- data.frame(G,H,I,J,K,L)
```

I want to assign

- 'a' value to any observation where 1 appears in either G or H or appears in both
- 'b' to observations where 1 appears in either/both of I and J.
- 'c' to observations where 1 appears in either/both K and L.

Comment: By assinging you mean that you want to turn all entries in a row to, for example, "a" or only those entries where there's a 1 or where there's a 0? Did you try anything that didn't work?

Comment: i have been tying to use the ifelse command
so eventually I want to create an additional variable in 'list' which states the corresponding a, b, c values for each observation

Comment: You mean for each row?

Comment: yes, if we assign it "categories"
names(list) = ( G, H, I, J, K, L, categories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple solution by creating a variable and then assigning values to it using subsets. Is this sufficient to your purpose?

```
list$Z <- NA
list$Z[list$G|list$H] <- "a"
list$Z[list$I|list$J] <- "b"
list$Z[list$K|list$L] <- "c" 
list
```

EDIT:
As per the suggestion by [David Arenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg), the code gets cleaner and better readable (and probably more efficient) by using `within()`:

```
list$Z <- NA
within(list, Z[G|H]<-"a"; Z[I|J]<-"b"; Z[K|L]<-"c")
```

Comment: I think this will be much efficient using `within`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I added a line of code that does it prettier using `within()`.